# Connect to internet with Qt for symbian

Tags: qt, symbian

I'm creating a Qt Symbian application and need to connect to internet. In some way I need to let the user choose a connection when the app starts. I could use Qt Mobility to get it working but when Nokia approves I wan't do publish my application on Ovi Store. As the Qt Mobility is not included in Qt 4.6 it might be a problem to publish my app later. So for this reason I'm thinking of using native APIs instead.

The idea is to use: qt_SetDefaultIap() to set the connection on start. I have been looking at this to actually understand what it is doing. If I have two connections that the app could use, one with WIFI and one through mobile internet, which one will qt_SetDefaultIap() choose? And can I in some way with native api make the user choose a connection on start up? (qt_SetDefaultIap seems to just set a default connection on its own, without user choice)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Qt 4.7 is now released, and although not all of the Mobility APIs have made it into the core, [QNetworkSession](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qnetworksession.html) has.

Mrbiggerm: it looks like you've found the [sym_iap_util.h](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/network-qftp-sym-iap-util-h.html) file that's included in the QFtp example code in the Qt SDK. Rather than calling qt_SetDefaultIap(), try calling qt_OfferIapDialog(), and passing its return value to qt_SetDefaultIapName(). That should do what you're after. (Although this is a bit of a hack, it's often a preferred option as it presents a native S60 UI rather than making you implement your own list of access points.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you expect to finish your program before Qt 4.7 release (I don't know the exact release date, but I'd estimate it will be around July), which AFAIK will contain Qt Mobility?

If the answer is no, don't worry about releasing issues, use custom build of QtMobility for development, wait for 4.7 and don't worry about releasing issues.

If the answer is yes, what stops you from deploying your program with custom QtMobility build? Internally it uses the same native API calls you want to use, not some super secret Nokia API, so there should be no problem with code validation (in fact, there will probably be less problems, since you won't have a chance to screw up code covered by QtMobility libraries).